# Batch - move files into folders that has at least one identical word

Tags: file, batch-file

I have these *folders* name inside directory A:

```
Veep
Vegas
Valentina
Valeria Medico Legale
```

I have this *file* list in the same directory A also

```
Veep - Season 1 BDMux
Valentina S01e01-13
Vegas S01e01-21
Valeria Medico Legale S01-02e01-16
```

For example

```
Veep [folder]
Veep - Season 1 BDMux [file]
```

***veep*** is identical word for folder and file name.
I want to move this file

```
Veep - Season 1 BDMux
```

inside this folder

```
Veep
```

using a file **.bat**

Any help?

Comment: I want reorder a long list of torrent files inside folders and I can't do it manually because i have more of 10000+ and names are like above

Comment: What code have you tried so far though? There's no code in your question to assist with. Without seeing what you've tried already, we can't help you much. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of would be using string substituition. Note that it might not do what you want if you have directories with matching substrings like:

```
Veep
Veeponic
```

Although it's not a perfect solution, and very costly if there are many directories, it might give you a start.

It receives the directory you want to proccess as parameter `%1`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd %1
for /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:-d`) do (
    set "_file=%%a"
    for /D %%b in (*) do (
        if NOT "x!_file:%%b=!" == "x!_file!" (
            echo moving "%%a" to %%b
        )
    )
)
popd
```

Save it as, let's say, `my_batch.bat` and, assuming your files/folders are in C:\songs\, call it from cmd with `my_batch C:\songs\`. The output will be

```
moving Valentina S01e01-13 to Valentina
moving Valeria Medico Legale S01-02e01-16 to Valeria
... and so on
```

Replace the `echo` line with the proper `move` command, e.g `move "%%a" %%b`

**Edit**: it should **NOT** work for directories with spaces in their names.

Comment: I tried to run the command, but nothing happens. What should happen?

Comment: @SuperSonic see edit. Again, this might not be very efficient when there are too many directories in the process, but it's a start.

Comment: Seems something is not correct. Look [HERE](http://peterlongx.altervista.org/Flash/Richieste/move.htm), please.

Comment: Sorry, there are some misunderstandings here... You are not supposed to double-click it, you should call it from the PROMPT passing the directory as argument... You can put the script at any folder in your computer. Also I forgot to put the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`(my fault). See edited. If you want to double click it, you should edit the `pushd %1` to `pushd C:\songs\ ` or path where your files are at. If running the script from the same directory as the files, you can comment the `pushd` and `popd` lines.

Comment: I try both method now but prompt and double click passing is not working: from command it tell me: the syntax of command is incorrect. [LOOK](http://peterlongx.altervista.org/Flash/Richieste/move_files_using_bat.htm)

Comment: @SuperSonic at your `move` line.. remove the "to" word. The `MOVE` command syntax is `move <file> <destination>`. More at `move /?`. Just remove that "to", as given by the answer's last line, and you should be fine. I just tested it here, same command, same file.

Comment: After your tip only exact `files name = folder name` are moving inside. For example a file text like **cane**.txt are moved in cane [folder] but **cane pazzo**.txt are not moved. Why?
Can you write me code exactly are you use, please?

Comment: @SuperSonic the problem is with the spaces in the filename. Putting double quotes around the `%%a` at `move "%%a" %%b` should be fine... HOWEVER, if your directories have spaces in their names, it's another problem that I couldn't solve... As said this should give you a north. **Tip**: run it in a prompt with `@echo on` to see what is happening each line. Good luck!